# GNOME 3.30 - changing activities overview close button

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell

I have GNOME 3.30 and tried to run 3.32 theme ([Adwaita - refresh](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1312531/)) which works somehow. Only the GNOME-SHELL Activities close button (picture) looks weird (there's a smudge behind the button). How can I fix this?

[image]

If this is not possible, where can I get a default Adwaita GNOME-SHELL .css file to modify it's colors?